# Android setTime() throwing NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, date

I'm trying to set a Date (highestNumber) with a long (highest) but it throws a NullPointer exception, I can't figure out why.

```
public static Date highestNumber = null;

long highest = 0;
    for (int x = 0;x <numberofData - 2;x++){
        long first = Array.Stop.get(x).getTime();
        long next = Array.Stop.get(x+1).getTime();
        if(x==0){highest = first;}
        if (highest < next){
            highest = next;
        }
    }
    highestNumber.setTime(highest);
```

Exception is being thrown on the setTime() line. highest gets a valid value of 1523328768914

Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.util.Date.setTime(long)' on a null object reference

Edit: I don't feel like this is a duplicate of "What is a nullpointerexception since i didn't realise a Date had to be initiaized. I thought it was just a variable like a string.

Comment: You never set `highestNumber` to anything other than null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
 highestNumber.setTime(highest);
```

Use

```
highestNumber= new Date(highest);
```

You haven't initialized your `highestNumber` object. Before using it at `highestNumber.setTime(highest);` That's why `NullPointerException`.

Comment: That works, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized `highestNumber`. You need to initialize `highestNumber` like this,

```
public static Date highestNumber = new Date();
```